# 405 Method Not Allowed - Firebug error trying to retrive a JSON feed from Youttube with Mootools

Tags: json, youtube, mootools

Getting an error in firebug and obviously no feedback inline.

"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/67621C8899ABADA5?alt=json"

```
var loadVideos = function()
{
    var req = new Request.JSON(
    {
        url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/67621C8899ABADA5?alt=json',
        method: 'get',
        onSuccess: function(jsonData)
        {
            //successCode
        }
    }).send();
}
```

I don't understnad whats wrong, I can request that URL in a browser but Request.JSON cant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use 'simple' JSON request to retrieve data from other domains (see same origin policy). You should instead use [JSONP](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Request/Request.JSONP) 
 i.e.

```
var req = new Request.JSONP(
{
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/67621C8899ABADA5?alt=json',
    method: 'get',
    onSuccess: function(jsonData)
    {
        //successCode
    }
}).send();
```